# Ajax call with external URL, doesnt work on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, ajax, cordova

First of all , i have a phonegap application on ios store.
I want to compare the version from the store with the version the user have.
so i can force the user to update if there is any new version in the store.

Down below , i wrote an example with random app from ios. it works fine on chrome console , returns the version number. but on the iphone it doesnt work.

```
        $.ajax({
        url: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997?mt=8&uo=4",
        context: document.body
        }).done(function(result) {
        alert($(result).find("li:contains('Version: ')").text().split(':')[1].trim())
        });
```

is apple doesnt allow calls from external links?
just to clear , version on ios store page is not having an id or dependent class, all it has is common class.

Comment: it may cross paltform origin problem not any iphone or other problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this it may help for your ajax calling.

```
$.ajax({
     url:"your url",
     dataType: 'jsonp',
     success:function(json){
         alert("Success");
     },
     error:function(){
         alert("Error");
     }      
});
```